# Gridview update only on userconfirmation

Tags: asp.net

while updating gridview rows I have to ask confirmation from user whether they want to continue update or not if their confirmation is yes then only I have to update row if confirmation no then no updation.

my gridview has 4 column when user will try to update first 2 columns will appear as a dropdown list based on data selected in a dropdown list I will ask confirmation from user whether they want to continue updation or not.

I have tried to call javascript confirmation but its running after postback so it is not helpful for me

Comment: please share your code of aspx and C#

Comment: Javascript confirmation is definitely a way to go. You should attach a client-side click handler to any control (e.g submit button), show the confirmation and - prevent submit if necessary.

Comment: yes javascript is the way to achive it .I didnt had onclientclick event previously i was trying to call through code bhiend ,now i added clientside event and it working fine for me